# How to select one string in each group and concatenate them in order?

Tags: c#

I am studying c# programming and this question is too hard for me.

[dog|cat|tiger|wolf][eats|bites|hunts][a bread|a meat|a fish]

select one in 1st group,

select one in 2st group,

select one in 3st group,

and combine them in order, so that you can make sentences.
(ex: dog eats a fish / Make sure that there is no duplicated sentence in results)

Then make a list or array which has all these sentences.

I am struggling for 6 hours. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

---

```
        String input = [dog|cat|tiger|wolf][eats|bites|hunts][a bread|a meat|a fish];
                String pattern = @"\[([^\[\]]+)\]";

                foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
                {
                    String mycontent = m.Groups[1].Value;
                    String[] values = mycontent.Split('|');
                    foreach (string finalm in values)
                    { MessageBox.Show(finalm); }

                 }
```

My codes just sequentially show dog, cat, tiger, wolf, eats, bites, hunts, a bread, ameat, a fish. At least I should make a sentence but I failed.

Comment: Could you write the piece of code you have tried?

Comment: I tried but nothing worked at all and so I have no clue to this.

Comment: I can not help if you don't even write a piece of code with the name of those arrays at least. You wasted 6 hours trying to solve it, waste 10 minutes to write down here a code that you think should work.

Comment: What restrictions or requirements are in place for this assignment/homework?  Does the input need to be in one, long string?  Are you required to use Regular Expressions?

Comment: @F.j.Jason So, basically you want all 36 (4 x 3 x 3) combinations of the parts?

Comment: MessageBox.Show(m + " " + finalm);

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code to this:

```
        String input = "[dog | cat | tiger | wolf][eats | bites | hunts][a bread | a meat | a fish]";
        String pattern = @"\[([^\[\]]+)\]";

        List<string[]> sentenceParts = new List<string[]>();

        foreach (Match m in Regex.Matches(input, pattern))
        {
            String mycontent = m.Groups[1].Value;
            String[] values = mycontent.Split('|');
            sentenceParts.Add(values);
        }
```

This way you will have a list called `sentenceParts` which contains every part of your final sentence. So in your example this list will contains:

- At index 0 - array with values: dog, cat, tiger, wolf. Array lenghth is 4
- At index 1 - array with values: eats | bites | hunts. Array length is 3
- At index 2 - array with values: a bread, a meat, a fish. Array length is 3

Now you just must write every combination of this `sentenceParts` list elements (arrays).

Is this solution is clear for you? Do you know what you must to do in the next step?